# Devexpress thememanager routed event already used when instantiating prism view

Tags: wpf, devexpress, prism, prism-4

I am building a business app based on a tiny variation of the Prism framework (couple of changes in behaviour but nothing in areas that would affect my issue.

I built a shell application, with a shell window that was created using the devexpress dxwindow wizard in vs2010.  I created a region inside a devexpress layout panel for my main content.  I then created a view, which also uses devexpress controls, in a separate project, that is then targeted at that region.

When the app starts and the view is registered and therefore "injected" (in the logical sense, not the DI or other programming concepts sense) into the region, I get one massive error that appears to be related to devexpress theming, but to be blunt, I don't know what the hell it's going on about.  I should point out my WPF knowledge is gaining fast but still reasonably low.

Here's the details...

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControl' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '14' and line position '10'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=14
  LinePosition=10
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
       at MyProject.Wpf.Modules.Partner.PartnerView.InitializeComponent() in c:\Workspace\Projects\MyProject\trunk\src\Wpf\MyProject.Wpf.Modules.Partner\PartnerView.xaml:line 1
       at MyProject.Wpf.Modules.Partner.PartnerView..ctor() in C:\Workspace\Projects\MyProject\trunk\src\Wpf\MyProject.Wpf.Modules.Partner\PartnerView.xaml.cs:line 24
  InnerException: System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException
       Message=Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.
       Source=System.Xaml
       LineNumber=0
       LinePosition=0
       StackTrace:
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.SetValue(Object obj, XamlMember property, Object value)
            at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
            at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx, XamlMember prop, Object value, Boolean onParent)
            at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
            at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
            at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndMember()
            at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
            at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)
            at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter)
            at System.Windows.SystemResources.ResourceDictionaries.LoadDictionary(Assembly assembly, String assemblyName, String resourceName, Boolean isTraceEnabled)
            at System.Windows.SystemResources.ResourceDictionaries.LoadGenericDictionary(Boolean isTraceEnabled)
            at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindDictionaryResource(Object key, Type typeKey, ResourceKey resourceKey, Boolean isTraceEnabled, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference, Boolean& canCache)
            at System.Windows.SystemResources.FindResourceInternal(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
            at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetThemeStyle(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce)
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.UpdateThemeStyleProperty()
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnThemeStyleKeyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
            at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
            at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_DefaultStyleKey(Object value)
            at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.CornerBox..ctor()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.PanelControllerBase.CreateScrollBars()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.PanelControllerBase.CheckScrollBars()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Controller.set_ScrollBars(ScrollBars value)
            at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ScrollControlController..ctor(IScrollControl control)
            at DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControllerBase..ctor(ILayoutControlBase control)
            at DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutGroupController..ctor(ILayoutGroup control)
            at DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControlController..ctor(ILayoutControl control)
            at DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControl.CreateController()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.PanelBase..ctor()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ScrollControl..ctor()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControlBase..ctor()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutGroup..ctor()
            at DevExpress.Xpf.LayoutControl.LayoutControl..ctor()
            at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.DefaultCtorXamlActivator.InvokeDelegate(Action`1 action, Object argument)
            at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.DefaultCtorXamlActivator.CallCtorDelegate(XamlTypeInvoker type)
            at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.DefaultCtorXamlActivator.CreateInstance(XamlTypeInvoker type)
            at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance(Object[] arguments)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
            at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
       InnerException: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
            Message=Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.
            Source=PresentationFramework
            LineNumber=0
            LinePosition=0
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
                 at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
                 at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
                 at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
                 at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
                 at MS.Internal.AppModel.AppModelKnownContentFactory.BamlConverter(Stream stream, Uri baseUri, Boolean canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean sandboxExternalContent, Boolean allowAsync, Boolean isJournalNavigation, XamlReader& asyncObjectConverter)
                 at MS.Internal.AppModel.MimeObjectFactory.GetObjectAndCloseStream(Stream s, ContentType contentType, Uri baseUri, Boolean canUseTopLevelBrowser, Boolean sandboxExternalContent, Boolean allowAsync, Boolean isJournalNavigation, XamlReader& asyncObjectConverter)
                 at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
                 at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.<Create_BamlProperty_ResourceDictionary_Source>b__1c4(Object target, Object value)
                 at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
                 at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
                 at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
            InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
                 Message=The type initializer for 'DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager' threw an exception.
                 Source=DevExpress.Xpf.Core.v10.2
                 TypeName=DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager
                 StackTrace:
                      at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager.get_TraceSwitch()
                      at DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.DefaultStyleThemeKeyExtension.RegisterThemeType()
                      at DevExpress.Xpf.Utils.Themes.DefaultStyleThemeKeyExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
                      at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.EvaluateMarkupExtensionNodeList(XamlReader reader, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
                      at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetKeyValue(KeyRecord key, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
                      at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetKeys(IList`1 keyCollection, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
                      at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.SetDeferrableContent(DeferrableContent deferrableContent)
                      at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext.<Create_BamlProperty_ResourceDictionary_DeferrableContent>b__168(Object target, Object value)
                      at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfKnownMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance, Object value)
                      at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member, Object obj, Object value)
                      at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst, XamlMember property, Object value)
                 InnerException: System.ArgumentException
                      Message=RoutedEvent Name 'ThemeChanged' for OwnerType 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' already used.
                      Source=PresentationCore
                      StackTrace:
                           at System.Windows.EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(String name, RoutingStrategy routingStrategy, Type handlerType, Type ownerType)
                           at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager..cctor()
                      InnerException:
```

The view does work in a static app, ie not using regions, and not using other devexpress controls outside the view.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a the same error a while ago.  What I found was that I had multiple versions of the controls on my PC and it was mixing versions of DevExpress controls (for me it was 11.1 and 11.2).

if you're using a DevExpress template it may be worth checking to see what version of the controls it's adding as references.  if you're using a newer version of the controls then this could lead to a version mismatch.